# Exoplayer vs Vitamio

Tags: android, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, vitamio, exoplayer

i'm writing android app that using HLS video Streaming from server and sometimes from local file.

which one is easier to implement? which one have better performance and features? I want to know pros and cons about exoplayer and vitamio(Standard Edition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I test [this link](http://devimages.apple.com/samplecode/adDemo/ad.m3u8) on samples of Vitamio and Exoplayer(both of samples written by main developers)

Exoplayer play it so faster. Furthermore Exoplayer samples have controller and better samples. I test both of them with other link and the result is the same; I going to use Exoplayer. according to this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6VjF638VObA) from google I/O Exoplayer performance is very good. apps like youtube and lynda.com use exoplayer too. I think exoplayer is easier to use. you can ask your question on issues page of exoplayer in github site; actually Exoplayer sample is better for using and undestanding

Comment: I'm using Exoplayer but for misc video. I guess Exoplayer is a good solution to use which will be (I guessing) used by most of app that don't use MediaPlayer as it's made by google.